# Set multiple login pages programatically with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In a Java Spring web application, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class is extended, and `configure(HttpSecurity http)` is used to set `authorizeRequests()`, `formLogin()`, etc.
Is it possible to specify multiple login pages in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`?
(I am **not** wondering if it is possible to do with XML(POM) or such, but in the configure function.)

For example, the end result would be like:

- Accessing `/admin/something` anonymously will take you to `/admin/` and force you to login on the admin page.
- Accessing `/user/something` anonymously will take you to `/user/` and force you to login on the user page.
- User and admin uses different `loginProcessingUrl`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done. Inside the `SecurityConfig` class by using the `@Order` annotation and declaring multiple classes that extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
public static class FirstConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { /* Settings for login page 1 here. */ }
}

@Order(2)
@Configuration
public static class SecondConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { /* Settings for login page 2 here. */ }
}

//And 3, and so on.
```

And then, in the respective `configure` methods, just set up the respective pages with `formLogin()` etc. as usual.